# how to pass json value from one page to another (Help needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, intel-xdk

using this script to parse the json value and display on first page (home.html)

I am using href tag to go on second page(Details.html)

```
$(function() {
    var RETAIL_CRM = [];
    var dmJSON = "https://cordova.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/CRM.jsp";
    $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
        $.each(data.RETAIL_CRM, function(i, f) {
```

I just want to send these three (f.S_NO , f.NAME and f.STATUS) values from home.html to Details.html

```
var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=Details.html?localStorage.getItem=" + f.S_NO + "&value1=" + f.STATUS + "&value2=" + f.NAME + ">" + f.S_NO + "</td>" + "</a>" + "<td>" + f.NAME + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.STATUS + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#list");
        });
```

These input types are on the second page (Details.html) i just want to set valued in it .

```
document.getElementById("crm_serialnumber").value = localStorage.getItem;
        document.getElementById("crm_name").value = value1;
        document.getElementById("crm_status").value = value2
    });
});
```

I need some help .Please .

Comment: Is PHP an option in your case?

Comment: no ,am not using php

Comment: Actually am developing hybrid mobile application, and using restapi to get value from server and displaying it on first page ,now i just want to send that particular value  to second page on which i'll click.

Answer (score 0):

firstly i would recommend using a JavaScript framework rather than plain HTML as it makes life much more easier (look into angular/react).

the easiest way for this is to use native `localStorage` function, which is supported in many browsers, but you are using it the wrong way.

usage as stated by [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value')
var key_val = localStorage.getItem('key')
```

you can also use the following snippet that i made for my usage:

```
var storage = {
    get: function (key, skipParse) {
        var data = localStorage.getItem(APP_PREFIX + key);

        if (data) {
            if (!skipParse) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
            }

            return data;
        }
    },
    set: function (key, value, skipParse) {
        if (!skipParse) {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(APP_PREFIX + key, value);
    },
    remove: function (key) {
        localStorage.removeItem(APP_PREFIX + key);
    }
}
```

look at my gist for complete details: [$helper](https://gist.github.com/imixtron/77d228b0ea6ebdbcc450730ae8ee36b6)

---

**UPDATED**
if you want to get query parameters, use the following code on the Details.html page:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// Usage will be like this
getParameterByName("value1") // will return f.STATUS in your case.
getParameterByName("value2") // f.NAME.. vice versa..
```

[getting query parameters using javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: // here am usng value ,value1 and value2 variables to store data,now i juts want to receive these value on second page .                            
    tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=Details.html?value="+f.S_NO+"&value1="+f.STATUS+"&value2="+f.NAME+">" + f.S_NO +"</td>" + "</a>" + "<td>"+ f.NAME+ "</td>"+ "<td>" + f.STATUS + "</td>" + "</tr>";  
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#list");